# Is this idiomatic sentence correct?

Tags: grammar, grammaticality, idioms

Hi everyone I saw a video on Instagram which the guy had split thousands of cards like dominoes and it made me think that he was doing it during the lockdown and then it came to me that **this is what lockdown made out of people**.
I wanted to know if it's correct or not.thank you all 
https://www.instagram.com/p/CCJUr8TI0F0/?utm_source=ig_web_copy_link

Comment: It's grammatical, but what do you mean by "correct"? Isn't something that's idiomatic always correct—in the sense of being something that has acceptable use?

Comment: I would say "This is what lockdown **did/does to** people."

Comment: I'm guessing you mean "*stacked*" thousands of cards?

Comment: Agree with @WeatherVane but I would say "**has done** to people."

Comment: Why do you say it is idiomatic?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you are trying to say.
If you think that the lockdown gave you valued extra time then you can say

> This is what the lockdown **made of** me.
> *The lockdown has allowed me to improve my French and learn to play guitar.*

But if you want to say that you considered it wasted time, you can say

> This is what the lockdown **did to** me.
> *I was so bored I even counted flies and stacked playing cards like dominoes.*

(Not that I really want to make any value judgements).
In both examples, you can remove 'the' before 'lockdown'.